# If statement with serialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I can write to a file with values of my objects, but I want something like this:  If (option1) serialise this object, else if option 2, serialise some other object, and so on.

My code works, but it's not obvious how to me, how I can have options to serialise and then de-serialise multiple objects. In short, consider a menu, if option selected, serialise that, or likewise for option 2, 3 etc.

Snippets of my working code are as follows, I am using Netbeans and running it via dos. This is a simple football game menu, trying to save and load a team name etc.

```
public class SerializeDemo
{
   public void Serialize()
   {


      ClubInfo club = new ClubInfo();
     club.teamName = "Arsenal";
     club.stadium = "Emirates";
     club.division = "Premier League";
      club.SSN = 11122333;
      club.stadiumCapacity = 60000;

      try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut =
         new FileOutputStream("C:/tmp/club.ser");
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(club);
         out.close();
         fileOut.close();
         System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in C:/tmp/club.ser");
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }


   }
} // end class SerializeDemo
```

I can then de-serialise it, by selecting my "load game" option, and it successfully reads from the file and displays the objects data. Here is the de-serialise code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class DeserializeDemo
{
   public void Deserialize()
   {
      ClubInfo club = null;
      try
      {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:/tmp/club.ser");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         club = (ClubInfo) in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
      {
         System.out.println("Club class not found");
         c.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
      System.out.println("Saved game loaded...");
      System.out.println("Name: " + club.teamName);
      System.out.println("Stadium: " + club.stadium);
      System.out.println("Division: " + club.division);
     // System.out.println("SSN: " + club.SSN);
      System.out.println("Stadium Capacity: " + club.stadiumCapacity);
    }
}
```

How can I serialise more than one object? I thought about using an array of objects, but then I have problems with string states belonging to the objects.

Comment: You can call `writeObject` and `readObject` more than once...

Comment: *but then I have problems with string states belonging to the objects*: what are the problems? Serializing an array or a List is your easiest option.

Comment: If you serialize multiple objects into one file, just make sure you read them in the same order. If you save different objects (different classes), use an 'instance of' check. Not really sure though if this is your problem, your question is rather unclear.